# Google OAuth - Authenticate using Javascript Frontend and Server Backend (Authorization Code Flow)

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

I am implementing Google authentication into my JavaScript web application. I would like to use the authentication code flow as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer).

What I want to do is...

1. User clicks a button and gets presented with the consent screen
2. He clicks "allow" and I get back the authorization code
3. I send the authorization code to my rest backend in order to exchange the authorization code to a `access_token`

The first 2 parts working perfectly as expected but I **cant get 3. to work**. 
I call `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token` from my backend posting the `code`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `redirect_uri` and `grant_type` (authorization_code). This works well, I checked it with fiddler (a web debugging tool). However I always get `unauthorized_client` as a result.

Any ideas?

Comment: and you are sending it as a HTTP POST?

Comment: Yes this should work. I want to get the acces token without redirect because i call it from my backend.

Comment: Redirect isn't for you its for Google to know where to return the access token to.  Did you add a Redirect URI for both fount end and backend?  are you using the same client id and client secret in both locations?

Comment: Because iam doing this from the backend there is no way to redirect the user. id and secret are the same, yes

Comment: Its an interesting idea.   even if you manage to get it to return in the backend how do you intend to send that information back to a Client sided JavaScript.  How will you find the correct user to send it to?

Comment: I would send the data back using the already running request between the user (passing in the code) and the server (try to get the access token). This is imho not a special concept as it is described in the google documentation and others. It is imho the idea behind the authentication code flow. The Google OAuth2 Playground does it the same way.

Comment: what do you mean by "This works well"  "However I always get unauthorized_client "  How does it work well if you are getting  unauthorized_client ?

Comment: The first 2 parts working well but the third did not. This really is nothing special here, the authorization code flow exists for exactly that.

Comment: trust me I know the flow http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/   but mixing client side and server side is not something I have tried.  I am going to have to set up a test project.  What type of project is it you created in the dev console?

Comment: i dont have any reason not trusting you. thanks a lot

Comment: mixing server-side and client-side works well. I find it provides the best combination of avoiding JS/Browser/Window issues, while freeing the server from ongoing auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing and reading i finally got it.

1. Even if i perform a POST request to get the access token in my backend i need to pass in the parameters (client_id, client_secret, etc...) with the query string NOT the body.
2. I need to provide the same redirect_uri in both requests (getting the code and getting the access_token)

Now it works great.

Comment: "need to provide the same redirect_uri in both requests" if that works for you then great, but I don't think it's strictky necessary. Provided both redirect URLs are registered, and are a strict character-by-character match between what's registered and what you provide at runtime, it should work.

Comment: @dknaack can you add a final flow to your post? I.e.
1) User clicks login
2) He redirected to facebook (whatever)
3) Once authorized -> redirected back to a frontend with code
4) frontend sends the code to a backend 
5) backend sends the code to get the token with redirect_uri fom step 3
6) backend gets token, replies with something else to frontend
7) profit?

I assume backend is not visible from outside so, all interaction happens throught the frontend, is that correct?